# How can I do multiple exposures with my Sony A100?

Tags: technique, sony, multiple-exposure

I have a Sony Alpha A100. 
Yeah, it's pretty old.

It still works really well, and I take some really good photos with it, the only concern I have is that it does not have "Double Exposure" or "Multiple Exposure".

I tried a lot on GIMP, but i'm not the kind of guy who's all into editing. I got GIMP cause it's free, and I didn't want to pirate Photoshop.

How do I edit photos as good as Dan Mountford? I almost cried looking at his photos. They're unbelievable.

Comment: Do you want to do this in camera, or learn how to do it in Gimp?

Comment: Also, of note: [Dan Mountford's work](http://www.flickr.com/photos/danmountford/sets/72157625371295037/) is not simple multiple exposures, but a lot of careful by-hand effort.

Comment: No idea about GIMP but Photoshop Elements which goes for under $100 USD does this extremely easily. For some reason most people get fixated on Photoshop, Elements does much more than most people need!

Comment: There is a way to do it on the camera? I tried alot, couldn't figure out anything.

Otherwise learning on GIMP would be fine too.

Answer (score 3):

A100 was my first DSLR. Although it was a very capable camera, I can tell from experience that you cannot do multiple exposures in camera.

Almost all image manipulation software offer capabilities to define layers and adjust their opacity, that way you can use any number of overlapped images to simulate multiple exposures.